# How to display `netgroups` in a presentable way (and why `tr` doesn't work)?

Tags: text-formatting, tr, nis

I tried to use `ypcat netgroups | tr '\n' '\n\n\n\n' | head` to put more lines between each paragraph, but it doesn't work. Why doesn't it work and how can I display `netgroups` in a more user-friendly manner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tr` replaces single characters with a single character; the arguments you've given instruct `tr` to replace `\n` with `\n`.

To add space between paragraphs, you can replace an empty line with four newlines using `sed`:

```
ypcat netgroups | sed 's/^$/\n\n\n\n/g'
```